# Manually Parse Multipart/formData in Nestjs

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I want to manually parse multipart/formData in middleware using request.on and request.end, access the fields only and save in logs. But in route handler I have been using  FileInterceptor() interceptor extract file from the request using the @UploadedFile() decorator. Is this even possible to keep handling file this way and also I read the stream chunks in my middleware before hand?